# How can I use custom properties to set different background on different pages?

Tags: wordpress

The problem isn't that complex (compared to the description I'll write :)) but I'd like to do this as correct as possible (e.g. I could be doing it wrong with Home.php), so I'll give you the whole context. 
As a part of my design, the page displays different background images. For that I use Supersized, "a fullscreen background slideshow built using the jQuery library". Some of my pages use one background image (no slideshow obviously :), and some use three. Also, I use javascript to detect the users monitor resolution and serve him an appropriate image size:

```
var imageToBeLoaded = "images/bg_index.jpg";
$(document).ready( function () {
if(window.screen.width > 1024) {
  imageToBeLoaded = "images/bg_index_large.jpg";
}});
```

So the problems are:

a) Home.php isn't a page accessible through WP-Admin so I can't give it custom fields.

Solution: `if  (isHome()){ setDefaultalues();}`

b) If I'm not on the homepage, I need to get the custom fields key/vaules but only for the properties that are related to the image background (and as I said before, ever page has 1 to N number of background images). For example, my About page has 5 properties, `bgImg1`, `smallImg1`, `bgImg2`, `smallImg2` and `greeting text`. That means I need to get all the variables and parse the name so I can get e.g. `bgImg1` and `bgImg2`. Additionally, Supersized needs a text description as another parameter, so the page needs to have two more parameteres, `desc1` and `desc2` which I also need to get and combine with the appropriate `bgImg` so I can generate output that looks like this (from the static page):

`{image : 'images/bg_rwanda.jpg', title : 'Rwanda Home'}, {image : 'images/bg_rwanda2.jpg', title : 'Rwanda School'}`

Pseudocode would look something like this:

```
var output = "{image : '";
var imageIsLarge= false;
if (getResolution() > 1024 ) { imageIsLarge= true; }
while (hasNextProperty()){
  Property prop = nextProperty();
  if (imageIsLarge) {
      if (prop.getKey().startsWith (bgImageL)){
         output += prop.getValue()+", title:";
         // etc. Also, I need to set the code to first get the first img, 
         // not just in any order and pair it with the first  description
```

Now this seems a bit complex and I have a feeling I could do it simpler, but I have no idea how.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields lists all the functions available to retrieve custom fields.

Comment: I must admit, I do not see any functions that helps me. I know how to get the fields, but I'm interested in parsing them "properly", though finding out that I can have multiple values for one key helped :)

Comment: There's nothing built in to do this for you elegantly. You have to write the code.

Comment: Thought so :( Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To set a different backgrounds on any page of WordPress all you need is CSS. WordPress automatically adds a unique class to each page or post so you'll need to target the  tags background in your style.css.

1. View the source of any WordPress page or post.
2. Note the classes assigned to the body i.e. `<body class="home page page-id-24 ...>` or post-id-25 if you're adding a background to a post.
3. Edit your style.css using `body.page-id-93{ background:blue !important;}` you might need to use !important because of other styles applied to the body.
4. Now you can do the same for every page or post.